# AngularJS Empty/Fill A Div

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a situation where I have a noJS Fallback implemented but I want to replace the entire div content. Html looks like this:

```
<div ng-controller="UserStatusCtrl">
     {{content}}
     <button>Login</button>
     <button>Register</button>
</div>
```

And I have a controller that works like this:

```
EngagementApp.controller('UserStatusCtrl', ['$scope', 'user',
function($scope, user) {

    if(user.status == 0) {
        $scope.content = ' <button>Login</button><button>Register</button>';
    } else if(user.status == 1) {
        $scope.content = '<div>Welcome' + user.user_name + '</div>';
    }

    return function($scope) {

    };
}]);
```

My question is how can I can replace ALL the content in the div and not just within the {{content}} area?

Comment: controllers are not supposed to know/generate any markup. as to what you are asking, you can use `ng-include` or `ng-show` directives.

Comment: don´t unse any kind of DOM modification in the controllers thats the reason why angularjs is declarative, use directives instead or pass the information through the scope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your view should be the one to show/hide the content.

```
EngagementApp.controller('UserStatusCtrl', ['$scope', 'user',
function($scope, user) {

  $scope.status = user.status;
  $scope.userName = user.user_name;
...
```

In your view:

```
<div ng-hide="status == 0">
  Welcome {{userName}}
</div>

<div ng-show="status == 0">
  <button>Login</button>
  <button>Register</button>
</div>
```